# Not seeing changes made to static files when using service worker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have registered a service worker for a reactjs app. 
I am using the cache api with it. When I make changes to my service worker script the `activate` event is called and I am able to update the the service worker

The challenge is with making changes to the source files. I am unable to see these changes even after updating the service worker, the only time I see changes is when I manually register a new service worker all together.

this is a snippet of the `activate` event listener

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
const expectedCacheNames = Object.values(CURRENT_CACHES);
event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => { 
        return Promise.all(
            cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
                if(!expectedCacheNames.includes(cacheName)) {
                    console.log('Deleting out of date cache: ', cacheName);
                    return caches.delete(cacheName);
                }
            })
        )
    })
   )
});
```

Is this problem specific to react?

code structured as follows

```
/src
  /components
  index.js //this is where I register service worker after calling ReactDOM
/public
  sw.js
  //other assests ...
```

Comment: use devtools to verify that chunk of code is actually working on the cache api... devtools can also delete the cache.

Comment: solution was to reload the client every time a new service was activated. reloading the client would fetch the new catched items. 
A prompt asking user if they want to view update was put at this point, and everything is working fine now